# TestCategory no longer works in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, appium, nunit, browserstack, vstest

I made some changes recently in my Appium Project taking the new .Net version and now I am having problems when I run the AzurePipelines tests. The Category Filters no Longer work due to these changes. These were working with Test Criteria I put into VsTest but now that does not work. I have tried adding SourceFilter tags into the yaml files but it still runs all the tests.
The below is apart of the logs stating it will not use the Source Filter.

```
    Test selector : Test assemblies
Test filter criteria : TestCategory=UserSubscription
Search folder : D:\a\r1\a
Action when minimum tests threshold not met : donothing
Minimum tests expected to be run: 0
VisualStudio version selected for test execution : latest
Attempting to find vstest.console from a visual studio installation with version [17.0,18.0).
Distributed test execution, number of agents in job : 1
Number of test cases per batch : 16
Run settings file : D:\a\r1\a\_Test.AppiumTestingOfMobileApps\AppiumTestingofmobileapps\env_ios.runsettings
Run in parallel : false
Run in isolation : false
Path to custom adapters : undefined
Other console options : undefined
Code coverage enabled : false
Diagnostics enabled : false
Rerun failed tests: true
Rerun failed tests threshold: 50
Rerun maximum attempts: 2
======================================================
Source filter: **\AppiumTesting*.dll,!**\*TestAdapter.dll,!**\obj\**
[command]D:\a\_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.229.0\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe --inputFile D:\a\_temp\input_402b3350-9851-11ee-bab6-bf3cf2211383.json
##########################################################################

TestPlatformVersion: 17.8.0-release-23468-02
EnvironmentUri: vstest://env/POB/_apis/release/63/11933/36568/1
QueryForTaskIntervalInMilliseconds: 3000
MaxQueryForTaskIntervalInMilliseconds: 10000
QueueNotFoundDelayTimeInMilliseconds: 3000
MaxQueueNotFoundDelayTimeInMilliseconds: 50000
===========================================
Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore
Run Attachments will be stored in LogStore
TestExecutionHost.Execute: Registered TestAgent : 725 : fv-az172-118-Hosted Agent-10
Provided settings file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <RunConfiguration>
        <EnvironmentVariables>
            <BROWSERSTACK_CONFIG_FILE>browserstack_iOS.yml</BROWSERSTACK_CONFIG_FILE>
        </EnvironmentVariables>
        <TestCaseFilter>TestCategory = UserSubscription</TestCaseFilter>
        <TargetFrameworkVersion>net7.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
Updated Run Settings:
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <EnvironmentVariables>
      <BROWSERSTACK_CONFIG_FILE>browserstack_iOS.yml</BROWSERSTACK_CONFIG_FILE>
    </EnvironmentVariables>
    <TestCaseFilter>TestCategory = UserSubscription</TestCaseFilter>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>net7.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <BatchSize>1000</BatchSize>
    <ResultsDirectory>D:\a\_temp\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
  </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
IsValidServiceResponse: Received None command..Service Workflow is not active
Creating run for selected test assemblies with following parameters
SourceFilter: ThisWontBeUsed TestCaseFilter: TestCategory=UserSubscription
Run title: TestRun_TestAutomationBSIntegration_Release-604
Build location: D:\a\r1\a
Build Id: 31009
Test run with Id 1059935 associated
```

Comment: I took off the Batch options and now it works. Unfortunately now the re-run failed tests quit working.